# Formatted Input from file.txt C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am making a library system that will save the data to the `file.txt`. I'm using `setw()` to format the out like this

```
void writeToFile(vector<Novel> novelList) {
    //write novel objects to file ;
    ofstream novelFile;
    novelFile.open("novel.txt", ios::app);
    for (auto x : novelList) {
        novelFile << setw(20) << x.getTitle()
            << setw(20) << x.getAuthor()
            << setw(8) << x.getID()
            << setw(15) << x.getGenre()
            << setw(15) << x.checkFiction()
            << setw(20) << x.checkBorrowed() << endl;
    }
    novelFile.close();
}
```

The file after output looks like this:

```
     Novel_A            Author_A    n001        Mystery            Yes                  no
     Novel_B            Author_B    n002         Comedy            Yes                  no
```

Now everytime I start the program I want read from the file how do I do that ? I want to input `Novel_A` to a string first. Novel_A can have spaces like "Moby Dick". How do I format the input to get the first 20 without the blank spaces ?

Comment: Can you add a separator symbol to your file,  like ";" in CSV?

Comment: Can you just use a text serialization library like `json` or `boost serialization`?

Comment: Typical solutions are to replace the wide spacing with a delimiter character that cannot appear in any of the strings and then use the `std::getline` method to read the text between the delimiters. If the spacing holds you can also read 20 characters for title and then trim off the trailing spaces, but note that many book titles and author names exceed 20 characters. You're usually much better off to go with the delimited text approach.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I just started learning  so I have no ida about that. I will look into it later. I guess I'll go with delimit symbol like AziMez and user4581301 advised. Thank you very much for your responses

Answer (score 0):

try this funny code!

use this code for wrting to file:

```
void writeToFile(vector<Novel> novelList) {
    //write novel objects to file ;
    ofstream novelFile;
    novelFile.open("novel.txt", ios::app);
    for (auto x : novelList) {
        novelFile << x.getTitle() << ','
            << x.getAuthor() << ','
            << x.getID() << ','
            << x.getGenre() << ','
            << x.checkFiction() << ','
            << x.checkBorrowed() << endl;
    }
    novelFile.close();
}
```

and use this for reading:

```
vector<Novel> readFromFile() {
    vector<Novel> vec;
    ifstream novelFile;
    novelFile.open("novel.txt", ios::in);
       
    while (!novelFile.eof()) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(novelFile, line);

        std::regex re("([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)");

        std::smatch sm;
        std::regex_match(line, sm, re);

        if (sm.size() == 7) {
            Novel x; 
            x.setTitle(sm[1].str());
            x.setAuthor(sm[2].str());
            x.setID(std::stoi(sm[3].str()));
            x.setGenre(sm[4].str());

            if (sm.[5].str() == "Yes")
                x.setFiction();

            if (sm[6].str() == "Yes")
                x.setBorrowed();

            vec.push_back(x);
        }  

    }  
       
    novelFile.close();
    return vec;

}
```

remember to include 'regex' header

Comment: This is a code-only answer. Code only answers don't explain to the reader what the code does or how it works, so they have a tendency to produce [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). The world has too many cultists already, so please add some explanation to the answer. Note: regex is a pretty heavy-weight tool if you just want to pick off commas.